# Apply Box Shadow on Container Element

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an inset pill using pure CSS:

[image]

Where the two color blocks are clickable separately.

But I can't figure out how to apply the box shadow to the containing element. The closest I got was using an `:after` element and positioning it over the links; but that covers up the links, making them un-clickable:

([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Kb9/1/))

```
<div class="pill">
    <a href="#" class="plus">&#10010;</a>
    <a href="#" class="circle">&#10687;</a>
</div><!--/.pill-->


.pill {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.35);
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    a {
        display: block;
        padding: 4px 6px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
        &.plus {
            background: #3c55b1;
            border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
            border-right: 1px solid darken(#3c55b1, 30%);
        }
        &.circle {
            background: #40be84;
            border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
            border-left: 1px solid lighten(#40be84, 15%);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the [pointer-events property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), but browser support is pretty shabby.

So what do we think? Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the spread property on the box shadow, so you want to create a border, instead using box shadow add a border to each element.

Remove the`:after` property and will get the normal behavior

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Kb9/4/)

Comment: This is probably the best solution for this particular problem. I wonder if you could fake a blur with multiple borders in different colors?

Comment: I don't why you want to fake a blur if you can actualy do it with Javascript [BlurJS](http://www.blurjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple,
draw your box-shadow from a, so it doesn't matter wich size they take.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/xwcKg

```
.pill {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background:#eee;
  padding:0.5em;

}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  width:1em;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  box-shadow:inset 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.35);
}
.plus {
  background: #3c55b1;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid #0c2571;
  position:relative;
}
.circle {
  background: #40be84;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  box-shadow:
    inset 0px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.35),
    inset 1px 0 0 #70de94
    ;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this hinges on the shadow being 100% opacity, otherwise it'll reveal that the shadow is outside and not inset.

Comment: okay i see it, it needs to update box-shadows back inside , still on the links :)

Comment: close, but I think the border colors for this particular example may be deceptive. If you change the `.circle` border to, say, white, you'll see that the borders overlap the shadows (not technically, of course, but it looks that way). :/